# When will a 15A fuse on 20A circuit burn up?

Tags: electrical

I have an old Amana gas furnace rated at 15.1 Amps. It is connected to a 20A circuit. There is also an inline fuse rated at 30A. That seems to defeat the purpose, so I would like to change it to 15A.

My question is when would this fuse burn:

1. As soon as installed because 20A current is flowing through it, OR
2. Only if the furnace tries to draw more than 15A from the circuit?

Comment: If the maximum current is 15.1 amps, the fuse probably will last.  Will depend on how sensitive that fuse is to current.  Most fuses/circuit breakers will burn out/trip faster the higher the current.  Would go with a 20 amp fuse in your case.  Most circuits are a pull demand idea instead of a push.  Why a .5 amp light does not burn out on a 20 amp circuit.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of a fuse box that is rated for 20A? Currently the 30A fuse is sitting in a porcelain lamp socket which I would like to replace.

Comment: The correct answer to 'when will fuse X burn' is 'when it can do most harm and provide least protection'.  Relying on a fuse to break at time S is normally a mistake: the best you can say is that it will go before the wiring does, if the wiring is properly installed...

Comment: fuses and breakers protect the wire not the device.  a 15 amp fuse makes no sense

Comment: Providing the _exact_ model of furnace as well as a picture of the name plate showing the manufacturer's rating information will be required to help you answer this question.

Answer (score 4):

Correct sizing for "continuous" loads (which a furnace is) is 125% load, or [takes precedence if specified] *as stated on the nameplate* for "**Minimum circuit ampacity**" and "**Maximum overcurrent protection**"

The 30A fuse **defeats nothing** - the 20A breaker should trip first, but if it doesn't (perhaps it's a Federal Pacific?) the fuse will back it up if things go wrong. Also, possibly the fuse is faster acting in the case of unusual and not expected in normal operation transients that the breaker will pass for a short period (assuming it was "done right" in the first place, not just randomly bodged in there.)

So, **unless otherwise stated on the nameplate**, 15.1A requires 18.75A, which rounds to 20A. That's 15.1/0.80, or 15.1 * 1.25 (same)

Using a 15A fuse would be inadvisable.

Comment: This is why I come to Stackexchange. Too many people elsewhere told me that I needed a 15A fuse. Another problem is that the fuse box I am about to install is rated only for 15A (Cooper Bussmann BP/SSU). I can't find any handy box covers that are rated for 20A. I may just have to use a lamp socket.

Comment: @cryptic0 what you're saying makes no sense. Handy box covers don't have current ratings. Do not use a lamp socket for a furnace. I'm rarely one to say this, but perhaps you should call an electrician.

Comment: @pericynthion Take a look: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Cooper-Bussmann-SSU-Series-2-1-4-in-Fuse-Box-Cover-with-Switch-BP-SSU/100192465

Answer (score 3):

> I have an old Amana gas furnace rated at 15.1 Amps. It is connected to a 20A circuit. There is also an inline fuse rated at 30A. That seems to defeat the purpose, so I would like to change it to 15A.

Are you going to also rewire your whole house to conform to ***"It Seems"*** logic, even if that conflicts with the electrical code???

This is called "sophomorism", or in more extreme cases, "Dunning-Kruger Effect".  Somebody learns a little in a field, and suddenly they think they're smarter than masters who've practiced in the field their whole life.

Here is the most important rule in NEC:

- **NEC 110.3(B) Equipment must be installed according to its labeling and instructions.** Backed with
- NEC 110.2 Equipment must be Approved (e.g. "UL Listed").

The reason for the rule is that UL approves the instructions *as part of* approving the equipment.  They vouch for the equipment's safety only when instructions are followed.

So I don't give a darn what "It Seems".  I care about **what the UL-approved instructions and labeling say to do**.   Search the web for them. **Read them** (implied in "follow them").  And then fit the fuse specified by the instructions.

You may infer that I don't give a darn about "what the last installer did" either.

If you're wondering why a motor might be over-fused, by all means take a semester in NEC Article 430 Motor Loads.  Motors are complicated, but the takeaway is that many motors have **overload** protection right on the motor itself (where it can detect the motor's actual temperature), so the breaker and fuse are not involved in overload protection, they are only concerned with short circuit and ground-fault protection. As such, it's not necessary to closely match load size to breaker size.

You also overlooked the "derate to 125%" rule, which requires continuous loads (with many load types presumed to be continuous) given wire and breaker for 125% of load. Thus a 15.1A load would require 18.9A wire and breaker.